# Передать параметр в компонент yii2

Tags: yii2

Мой компонент:

```
<?php
    namespace backend\components\example;
    use yii\base\Component;
    use yii\helpers\Html;

    class example extends Component {
        protected $token;
        public $options;
        public $id;
        public $secret;
        public $callback;
        protected $server = 'http://some.server.ru/';

        public function __construct($options, $config) {
            parent::__construct($config);
            var_dump($options);
        }

        public function example() {
        }

        public function init() {
            parent::init();
        }

        public function start() {
            echo $this->token;
        }
    }
?>
```

файл конфигурации:

```
<?php
'components' => [
    'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'app*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'example' => [
        'class' => 'backend\components\example\example',
        'options' => [
            'id' => 'b1d249b3a53d47e6b7c4e2d334dbe601',
            'secret' => '5dc47ecbd5ae4fe9b1692957b2016b6e',
            'callback' => 'https://amgexpert.com',
        ],
    ],
];
?>
```

ошибка:

```
Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
Missing required parameter "options" when instantiating "backend\components\example\example"
```

1. Как правильно передать/обработать настройки моего компонента? Пытался перехватить эту переменную options и в функции __construct и в init - везде вываливается ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно заворачивать его в options.
Просто передавай параметры они отправятся уже в конструктор объекта:

```
'example' => [
    'class' => 'backend\components\example\example',
    'id' => 'b1d249b3a53d47e6b7c4e2d334dbe601',
    'secret' => '5dc47ecbd5ae4fe9b1692957b2016b6e',
    'callback' => 'https://amgexpert.com',
],
```